# How do I use getchar() like scanf()?

Tags: c, scanf, getchar

I was shown this program to read an entire string:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
int something;
printf("Enter something \n");
while (scanf("%c", &something)==1) {
    printf("%c", something);
}
return 0;
}
```

When I enter `hello world` it outputs `hello world`.

Can someone please explain why it doesn't output:

```
h
e
l
l
...
```

because I thought loops go over one letter at a time I'm confused as to why it didn't output like that. Now, I tried to write a program that does the same thing using getchar instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char c;

   printf("Enter character: ");
   c = getchar();

   printf("Character entered: ");
   putchar(c);

   return(0);
}
```

When I enter `hello world` this program just outputs `h`. How can I use getchar to do the same thing as the first program? Also, what are the differences between getchar and scanf?

Answer (score 0):

`getchar()` takes one character input at a time. If you want it to read a whole string or a character array, you may use a `while loop` or a `for loop` to store each character one by one. Eg : `c[i]=getchar()` `for i = 0 to string length`, or `while c[i]!='\n'`

Answer (score 0):

In the first program, the problem is the line

> printf("%c", something);

It's missing a newline character, it should be

```
printf("%c\n", something);
```

if you want to print one character per line.

The problem with the second one is that you are reading only one character with getchar() function.  You can't read in the whole string on the same line with getchar(), you can try gets(char* s) instead.  And you need to loop over putc() to dump all the characters.